# Prevent new windows/tabs opened from iframe

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, tabstop

I searched a lot about this, but I have not found a solution.

I need the contents of an iframe (different domain) cannot open new pages/windows/tabs on my browser. Within that iframe there are some javascript elements that clicking on it open new windows. As we are in different domains, I can not block them with javascript. I also tested Firefox extensions as BlockSite or LeechBlock, but fail to stop my problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions? (Only Firefox PLZ)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the solution. I leave it as it would be helpfull to someone.

You only have to modify the parameter dom.popup_allowed_events from about:config. By default comes with "change click dblclick mouseup reset submit touchend". I set it to "" and everything went fine.